# Java instrumentation with modules

Tags: java, module, instrumentation, java-module, javaagents

I am trying to run a `javaagent` in a modular application, but I cannot make it work from command line. I have created the smallest repository possible:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── manifest
└── mods
    ├── main
    │   ├── module-info.java
    │   └── tsp
    │       └── App.java
    └── modifier
        ├── module-info.java
        └── tsp
            └── Agent.java
```

**mods/main/module-info.java**

```
module main {
}
```

**mods/main/tsp/App.java**

```
package tsp;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

**mods/modifier/module-info.java**

```
module modifier {
    requires java.instrument;
}
```

**mods/modifier/tsp/Agent.java**

```
package tsp;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    }
}
```

**Makefile**

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: clean build_main build_agent run

build_agent: clean
    echo -e "Premain-Class: tsp.Agent\nCan-Retransform-Classes: true\n" > manifest
    javac --module-path mods/modifier -d output/modifier $$(find mods/modifier -name *.java) && \
        jar --create --file output/modifier.jar --manifest manifest -C output/modifier .

build_main: clean
    javac --module-path mods/main -d output/main $$(find mods/main -name *.java)

run: build_main build_agent
    java -javaagent:output/modifier.jar --module-path output/main --module main/tsp.App

clean:
    rm -rf output
```

The `manifest` is created automatically from the `Makefile`.

---

When I execute `make run`, the output is:

```
rm -rf output
javac --module-path mods/main -d output/main $(find mods/main -name *.java)
echo -e "Premain-Class: tsp.Agent\nCan-Retransform-Classes: true\n" > manifest
javac --module-path mods/modifier -d output/modifier $(find mods/modifier -name *.java) && \
        jar --create --file output/modifier.jar --manifest manifest -C output/modifier .
java -javaagent:output/modifier.jar --module-path output/main --module main/tsp.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tsp.Agent
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:431)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
make: *** [Makefile:14: run] Aborted (core dumped)
```

Instead, when I change the `run` target in the `Makefile` to:

```
run: build_main build_agent
    java -javaagent:output/modifier.jar --class-path output/main tsp.App
```

Everything works perfectly. I do not want to use build tools like Gradle or Maven because I would like to understand why it does not work from command line. I have read [Loading agent classes and the modules/classes available to the agent class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) but it is not completely clear to me honestly. I have made many tries like using `--add-modules output/modifier` but without success.

```
> java --version

openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by the other answer, Java Agents are loaded into the Unnamed module. This hides the problem with your setup. When you run your modules with

```sh
java -javaagent:output/modifier.jar --add-modules modifier \
  --module-path output/main:output/modifier.jar --module main/tsp.App
```

you’ll get

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package tsp in both module modifier and module main
```

Within one module layer, packages unambiguously belong to one module and it is an error to have two modules with the same package name.

The classes on the class path do not undergo such check. Instead, in your setup, the package `tsp` has been associated with the `main` module and the runtime did not even try to look for `tsp.Agent` in the class path. Since the `tsp` package has been associated with the `main` module, it only looked in the `output/main` location and did not find the class.

The takeaway is, you have to use different packages. When you use different package names, the command line

```sh
java -javaagent:output/modifier.jar --module-path output/main --module main/tsp.App
```

works, but the Agent will be loaded into the Unnamed module. The `module-info` will be ignored. However, you can enforce the agent to be loaded as a module by adding it manually. This utilizes the behavior described above; when a module has been added to the environment, it’s package ownership takes precedence.

When I rename your agent’s package to `agent` and use the command line from the beginning of my answer, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl (in module java.instrument) cannot access class agent.Agent (in module modifier) because module modifier does not export agent to module java.instrument
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
```

which proves that the agent has been loaded as a module. Unlike the Unnamed module, it does not export everything by default.

When I change the Agent’s `module-info`

```java
module modifier {
    requires java.instrument;
    exports agent to java.instrument;
}
```

<sup>Mind that I renamed the agent’s package to `agent`, so the agent main class is `agent.Agent`</sup>

It runs successfully.

Changing the Agent’s class to

```java
package agent;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("Agent started in " + Agent.class.getModule());
    }
}
```

does then print

```
Agent started in module modifier
```

as intended.

As a side note, your approach to compile the modules is unnecessarily complicated. You can compile a complete module using, e.g.

```sh
javac --module-source-path mods -d output -m main
```

or even

```sh
javac --module-source-path mods -d output -m modifier,main
```

to compile both in one go.

Comment: One problem to be aware of when using an agent in a module: You manually have to add read edges at runtime when you transform classes - [by default, only a read edge is added to the unnamed module of the system class loader and the unnamed module of the bootstrap class loader.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#bcimodules)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, that’s why I gave the missing `exports` so much room in the answer. It’s important to be aware that using explicit modules creates more responsibilities regarding dependency management.

Comment: The comment was more geared towards transforming a class so it calls a method of the agent - for this to work, the module containing the call needs to read the agent module.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn “responsibilities regarding dependency management” was meant to be general. Since an Agent can instrument code to use another module’s code, not necessarily the Agent’s code, this applies even when the Agent is not inside a module.

Answer (score 1):

Agents cannot be modular, they are automatically loaded onto the system class loader's class path, into the unnamed module.

I assume that the JVM does not properly cover the case where an agent is modular and crashes internally when trying to invoke it.

Have you tried this with a recent Java 11/17? I assume this can be fixed by removing the agent's module descriptor.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelWinterhalter , but I am missing a step: I build the agent as a module and it works perfectly fine when I `make run` with the `--class-path` instead of `--module-path`. Isn't the java agent loaded into the unnamed module, independently if I run `java --module ...` or `java --class-path ... myclass`?

Comment: I would assume that the JVM ignores module info for classpath components, because by definition they will be placed in the unnamed module, which contradicts anything you defined in your module info. The outcome is similar to running libraries with Java module information on JDK 8. It would also work, but of course without JMS features.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex , so it cannot read the `tsp.Agent` class because it is automatically put into the unnamed module and therefore inaccessible from named modules?

Comment: That is not what I wanted to say. Anyway, I was just offering an educated guess. Whatever the exact role cause for that ugly stack trace is, I think the JVM ought to do better than that. It might be worth opening an OpenJDK issue, if there is not one already. I think that Rafael has the necessary privileges to open one and the skills to explain it well, otherwise you have to start doing it via Oracle first.

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry I misunderstood, I just cannot connect the dots right now because of my lack of knowledge on this topic.

Comment: My suspicion is that, if you put the agent on the module path, the code that attempts to load the agent fails to access it. If you add an agent via `-javaagent`, it is placed on the class path and it likely expects it to be there. To make things worse, your agent and application share a package `tsp`. This package cannot be on the module path and belong to the agent at the same time in such a case.

Comment: The “ASSERTION FAILED” seems to happen always when initializing a Java Agent fails; it’s a red herring. The `ClassNotFoundException` is the only problem here and it is a direct result of the split package issue.